# How to detect two object collide or not?

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript

I am making one unity game in which two objects having collider in which I have select isTriger and does not have rigid body, if I put the rigid body then they are kinematic object, So that gravity did not effect on that object, Even also i don't want any physic operation on this object also. but I want to detect whether this two object collide which each other or not.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

When 2 colliders make contact with each other,

- OnCollisionEnter2D
- OnCollisionExit2D
- OnCollisionStay2D

are called for 2D games, likewise for 3D(remove 2D in names) also.

---

Check out this link: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, but unity use the phsysics engine to detect collision so you have to add the rigidbody to the item you want to to plug the script.
PS:remeber if you want to detect collisions with Trigger collider, you need to use

```
void OnTriggerEnter(){
     //your code
}
void OnTriggerStay(){
     //your code
}
void OnTriggerLeave(){
     //your code
}
```

Comment: You can also write a simple collider of you of ( avoid ).